# Destroy has many through association deleting all associations of that id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This was working a few weeks ago but after adding paper_trail versioning I now have the following bug when doing an update.

A Miniature has many Sculptors through the Sculptings table. When I edit a Miniature by removing an associated Sculptor and then submit the update, the Miniatures Controller destroys all the entries in the Sculptings table belonging to the removed Sculptor, rather than just the entry for the updated Miniature.

Here is my Miniature update action

```
def update
    @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])
     if params[:miniature][:"release_date(2i)"] == ''
      # no month is given, insert fake month and day
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(2i)"] = '1'
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] = '1'
      mask = 4 # 100
    elsif params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] == ''
      # no day is given, insert a fake day
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] = '1'
      mask = 6 # 110
    else
      # full-date
      mask = 7 # 111
    end
    if params[:sculptors][:id]
      ## Convert ["", "1","2","4","8"] to [1,2,4,8]
      params[:sculptors][:id] = params[:sculptors][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i) 
      ## Get the sculptor_id from sculptings already present in database [1,2,5,6] 
      old_sculptors = @miniature.sculptings.pluck(:sculptor_id)
      ## Find the new sculptors to be added [1,2,4,8] - [1,2,5,6] = [4,8]
      new_sculptors = params[:sculptors][:id] - old_sculptors 
      ## Find the old_sculptors to be deleted [1,2,5,6] - [1,2,4,8] = [5,6]
      old_sculptors = old_sculptors - params[:sculptors][:id] 
      ## Build new_sculptors [4,8]
      new_sculptors.each do |sculptor|
        @miniature.sculptings.build(:sculptor_id => sculptor)
      end
      ## Delete old_sculptors [5,6]
      Sculpting.destroy_all(:sculptor_id => old_sculptors)
    end
    if @miniature.update_attributes(miniature_params.merge(date_mask: mask))
      flash[:success] = "Miniature updated. #{undo_link}"
      redirect_to @miniature
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Here is the relevant bit of the form (it uses a multiselect).

```
<div class="control-group">
        <%= f.fields_for(@sculpting) do |scf| %>
          <%= scf.label :sculptors, 'Sculpted by', class: "control-label" %>
            <div class="controls">
              <%= collection_select( :sculptors, :id, @all_sculptors, :id, :fullname, 
                   {:selected => @miniature.sculptors.map(&:id)}, 
                   {class: 'multiselect', multiple: true}) %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

Here is the log output for an update where all I did was remove the association with Sculptor 6 from Miniature 43 but as you can see it also removes all the other associations with Sculptor 6, those being with Miniatures 42 and 41.

```
Started PATCH "/miniatures/43" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-04 15:43:57 +0100
Processing by MiniaturesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xnfOwotMS39buQFCYnUqZTvFajc0hlz+LIVo4cN02q0=", "miniature"=>{"name"=>"A Aa Perry", "material"=>"Hard Plastic", "pcode"=>"", "release_date(1i)"=>"", "release_date(2i)"=>"", "release_date(3i)"=>"", "set"=>"0", "quantity"=>"", "random"=>"0", "notes"=>"", "comment"=>"Removed sclptr"}, "manufacturers"=>{"id"=>["", "1"]}, "scales"=>{"id"=>["", "3"]}, "sculptors"=>{"id"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"43"}

  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

  Miniature Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "miniatures".* FROM "miniatures" WHERE "miniatures"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "43"]]

   (0.4ms)  SELECT "sculptings"."sculptor_id" FROM "sculptings" WHERE "sculptings"."miniature_id" = ?  [["miniature_id", 43]]
  Sculpting Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "sculptings".* FROM "sculptings" WHERE "sculptings"."sculptor_id" IN (6)

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "sculptings" WHERE "sculptings"."id" = ?  [["id", 46]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("created_at", "event", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "whodunnit") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 04 Jun 2014 14:43:57 UTC +00:00], ["event", "destroy"], ["item_id", 46], ["item_type", "Sculpting"], ["object", "---\nid: 46\nsculptor_id: 6\nminiature_id: 41\ncreated_at: 2014-06-04 11:17:26.000000000 Z\nupdated_at: 2014-06-04 11:17:26.000000000 Z\n"], ["whodunnit", 4]]
  PaperTrail::Version Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."item_id" = ? AND "versions"."item_type" = ? ORDER BY versions.created_at ASC, versions.id ASC  [["item_id", 46], ["item_type", "Sculpting"]]
   (3.6ms)  commit transaction

   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "sculptings" WHERE "sculptings"."id" = ?  [["id", 47]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("created_at", "event", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "whodunnit") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 04 Jun 2014 14:43:57 UTC +00:00], ["event", "destroy"], ["item_id", 47], ["item_type", "Sculpting"], ["object", "---\nid: 47\nsculptor_id: 6\nminiature_id: 42\ncreated_at: 2014-06-04 14:42:07.000000000 Z\nupdated_at: 2014-06-04 14:42:07.000000000 Z\n"], ["whodunnit", 4]]
  PaperTrail::Version Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."item_id" = ? AND "versions"."item_type" = ? ORDER BY versions.created_at ASC, versions.id ASC  [["item_id", 47], ["item_type", "Sculpting"]]
   (3.3ms)  commit transaction

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "sculptings" WHERE "sculptings"."id" = ?  [["id", 48]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("created_at", "event", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "whodunnit") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 04 Jun 2014 14:43:57 UTC +00:00], ["event", "destroy"], ["item_id", 48], ["item_type", "Sculpting"], ["object", "---\nid: 48\nsculptor_id: 6\nminiature_id: 43\ncreated_at: 2014-06-04 14:42:31.000000000 Z\nupdated_at: 2014-06-04 14:42:31.000000000 Z\n"], ["whodunnit", 4]]
  PaperTrail::Version Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."item_id" = ? AND "versions"."item_type" = ? ORDER BY versions.created_at ASC, versions.id ASC  [["item_id", 48], ["item_type", "Sculpting"]]
   (2.5ms)  commit transaction

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  commit transaction
  PaperTrail::Version Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."item_id" = ? AND "versions"."item_type" = ? ORDER BY versions.created_at DESC, versions.id DESC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 43], ["item_type", "Miniature"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/miniatures/43
Completed 302 Found in 166ms (ActiveRecord: 15.9ms)
```

Like I say this was all working perfectly a couple of weeks ago but I've added so much paper_trail versioning since then that I really don't want to revert to an older version. I'm also not at all sure where the problem arises. Very frustrating to be stuck on this after I had it working. Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading and re-reading the update action I thought it likely that the line

```
Sculpting.destroy_all(:sculptor_id => old_sculptors)
```

Was no longer limiting itself to the Sculpting lines as defined by

```
old_sculptors = @miniature.sculptings.pluck(:sculptor_id)
```

and that it might need restricting to the current @miniature again.

I changed it to

```
Sculpting.where(:miniature_id => @miniature.id).destroy_all(:sculptor_id => old_sculptors)
```

and the problem was solved.

I was pretty sure it was working as intended originally but that doesn't seem possible now. It must have always been buggy. Anyway, problem solved it seems.